# How to get metadata/exif from a mp4 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metadata, exif, avasset

I have a UIImagePickerController to pick a video with. How can I view the exif data of the video and or the metadata? This is what I have tried so far. What else can I try? Here is a sample file I've been using. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6zrWYe4_e7iNVM4MWRXTjRnWk0/edit?usp=sharing

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info{  



//method 1

NSLog(@"%@",info); 
NSURL* assetURL=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
//This is what my asseturl looks like
//assets-library://asset/asset.MP4?id=A37A6038-DAA7-4D96-B0C6-1A5E1FC6D8F9&ext=MP4
NSString* value=NULL;
[assetURL getResourceValue:&value forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",value); //this is always nil



//method 2
AVURLAsset *videoAss = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];

//I get nothing back from this
NSLog(@"%@",[videoAss metadataForFormat:AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeMetadata]);

//I get nothing back from this either
 NSLog(@"%@",[videoAss metadataForFormat:AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon]);


//method 3

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[assetLibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    //My asset is non nil
    NSLog(@"%@",asset);
    ALAssetRepresentation* rep=[asset defaultRepresentation];

    //My metaData is nil.
    NSDictionary* metaData=[rep metadata];
    NSLog(@"%@",metaData);
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(error);
}];
}
```

Comment: see [videoAss availableMetadataFormats] to find what metadata sets your file has.